# PHP warning: in_array() wrong datatype for second argument in

Tags: php, arrays, warnings

I recently got this error on my error log:

```
   PHP Warning:  in_array() [<a href='function.in-array'>function.in-array</a>]: Wrong datatype for second argument in... on line 423
```

and refers to the following piece of code:

```
    <?php foreach($services_a as $key=>$service) { ?>
    <div class="oneservice">
    <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="service<?php echo $key; ?>"<?php if( in_array($key, $services) ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
    <label for="service<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $service; ?></label>
    </div>
```

Any views are very welcome,
Thanks

Comment: Is `$services` an array? You can use `var_dump()` to find out

Comment: It is defined as follows: `$services = $_POST['services'];
 if ($services && is_array($services)) {
  foreach ($services as $i => $service) {
   $service = (int)$service;
   $array = array(
    'key' => 'services',
    'value' => '%"'.$service.'"%',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
   );
   $meta_query[] = $array; unset($array);
  }
 }`

Comment: `$services_a = array(
 "1" => _d('Green)',263), 
 "2" => _d('Blue',264), 
 "3" => _d('Yellow',265), 
 "4" => _d('Red',266), 
 "5" => _d('Purple',267), 
 "6" => _d('Red',268), 
);`

Answer (score 4):

`in_array()` checks for the value, not the key.

Use `array_key_exists()` if xou want to check for the key:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="service<?php echo $key; ?>"<?php if( array_key_exists($key, $services) ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
```

When you open the form the first time, your `$_POST['services']` will be empty. to overcome the error, initialize an empty array if nothing is coming from post:

```
$services = is_array($_POST['services') && count($_POST['services']) > 0 ? $_POST['services'] : array();
```

Comment: `PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in` I get this error

Comment: I've added some code to initialize the `$_POST['services']` if it's empty.

Comment: Will this be of any help `$services_a = array(
 "1" => _d('Green)',263), 
 "2" => _d('Blue',264), 
 "3" => _d('Yellow',265), 
 "4" => _d('Red',266), 
 "5" => _d('Purple',267), 
 "6" => _d('Red',268), 
);`

Answer (score 0):

You should check "an array"
Is it an array?

```
<?php if(is_array($services)): ?>
 <?php if( in_array($key, $services) ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$services_a = array(
 "1" => _d('Green)',263), 
 "2" => _d('Blue',264), 
 "3" => _d('Yellow',265), 
 "4" => _d('Red',266), 
 "5" => _d('Purple',267), 
 "6" => _d('Red',268), 
);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you called the array you are iterating for `$services_a` but the array you use for second argument in `in_array()` is called plain `$services`. Problem is probably that the second argument has a NULL value, which gives you the warning.